# Add multiple audiences in token descriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, access-token

I have the code below:

```
   var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
    {
        NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(client.AccessTokenLifetime),
        Issuer = issuer,
        Audience = (await _apiResourcesStore.FindByScopesNameAsync(tokenRequest.Scope.Split(" ").ToList())).Select(p => p.Name).ToArray(),
    }
```

and I want add multiple audiences, but Audience type is `string`. Is there any way to cheat the token descriptor? Or maybe there is an alternative for token descriptor?

Comment: Why not generate a token for each audience you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it and now it's working:

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(client.AccessTokenLifetime),
                Issuer = issuer,
                Claims = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, (await _apiResourcesStore.FindByScopesNameAsync(tokenRequest.Scope.Split(" ").ToList())).Select(p => p.Name).ToArray() }
                }
            };
```

I just added new Claim.